# How should the ZIndex be implemented?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, z-index

I have a ListBox, populated with a CollectionViewSource so that the items will be grouped.

```
        <ListBox
            x:Name="Positions"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            BorderThickness="0"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsItems}}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            SelectionMode="Extended">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Separator
                                Margin="-8,-19,10,11"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsPartOfAverageGroup, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.ZIndex="1"/>
                            <Separator
                                Width="40"
                                Margin="-10,0,8,0"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsPartOfAverageGroup, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Image
                                Height="12"
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                Source="/Images/2017/Editable.png">
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Ellipse
                                    Width="8"
                                    Height="8"
                                    Margin="1,0,0,0"
                                    Grid.ZIndex="10000"
                                    Fill="#0589D1" />
                                <Button
                                    Margin="15,0,0,0"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                    cal:Message.Attach="SelectAverageGroup($dataContext)"
                                    Content="{Binding Name}" />
                                <StackPanel.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </StackPanel.Style>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

Here is my CollectionViewSource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsItems" Source="{Binding Items}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="AverageGroup.Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You can see in the DataTemplate for the ListBox that I am wanting to draw lines connecting the Group Header with the grouped items.  Here is a picture to clarify:

[image]

I would like the blue circle to be in front of the gray line, not the reverse.  I have attempted to set the ZIndex for the vertical gray separator and the ZIndex for the blue circle to 1000, so that the latter will be in front.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Do the blue circle and the gray line have the same parent?

Comment: No, the blue circle is defined in the GroupStyle, the lines defined in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: ZIndex controls what's on top of what within a given parent. The two controls must have some ancestors that are sibling children of the same parent; that's where you need to set the ZIndex. Or just rearrange things so the blue circle is defined later in the XAML.

Comment: Well the ItemTemplate and GroupStyle are both siblings under the common parent ListBox.  So you have to set the ZIndex on siblings directly under the common parent?

Comment: No, they’re not siblings. I mean child controls of a common  parent. They’re not even controls.